# Histogram from two coupled arrays

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have two arrays: one for particles locations `X` and one for the corresponding velocities `V`.
I want to create a histogram for the particle locations, where each bin width is 1, and for each bin I want to calculate the variance of the associated velocities of the particles in that particular bin.

Doing the location histogram is straightforward:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randn(1000)
V = 3*np.random.randn(1000) + 40

bins = np.arange(int(X.min()) - 0.5, int(X.max())+1.5, 1)

plt.hist(X, bins=bins, facecolor = '#2ab0ff', edgecolor='#169acf', linewidth=0.7)
```

However, I want to calculate the variance of the velocities for the particles in each bin according to `V` vector (if there are 3 particles in the bin centered at -3, I want to calculate the variance of the 3 velocity values).
I’m not sure how to do it efficiently, since there is no tracking of the mapping from the `X` vector to the histogram.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the function [scipy.stats.binned_statistics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html).

Here is an example.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randn(1000)
V = 3*np.random.randn(1000) + 40

hist, bins, stst = binned_statistic(X, V, statistic='std')

bin_centres = (bins[1:] + bins[:-1]) / 2

plt.plot(bin_centres, hist)
plt.show()
```